# The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: home-page-component

i am creating a HTML area Home page layout component.my code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HomePageComponent xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <body>&lt;div id=&quot;demoContainer&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;        try{  var pa=document.getElementById(&quot;demoContainer&quot;).parentNode.parentNode;                 pa.style.display = &quot;none&quot;;                }              catch(err){             alert(&apos;There was an error on this webpage=&apos;+err.description);        } &lt;/script&gt;nbsp;&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js&quot; &gt;&lt;/script&gt;  &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;   
    window.onload = function(){
        var actionLinks = document.getElementById("PendingProcessWorkitemsList_body").getElementsByClassName('actionLink');
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i< actionLinks.length ; i++)
      var text = accountLinks[i].textContent || accountLink[i].innerText;
      if(text == 'Approve / Reject')
          accountLinks[i].setAttribute('href','/apex/firstPage');
    }

          &lt;/script&gt;   &lt;/div&gt;</body>
    <pageComponentType>htmlArea</pageComponentType>
    <width>wide</width>
</HomePageComponent>
```

and when i try to save it .it is giving me error

```
The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.   Override.homePageComponent  /Custom Approval Process/src/homePageComponents line 7  Force.com save problem
```

error is in for loop Line 7 is of for loop

Comment: on line 7 `i < actionLinks` is working as html markup not script and it is unable to find closing `>`. This is happening beacause of html encoding you have done.

Comment: Ok. I have posted it as solution. @user133421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 7 `i < actionLinks` is working as html markup not script and it is unable to find closing `>`. This is happening because of **html encoding** you have done.